# Installing CrystalReportsForVisualStudio.msi on Client Machine for Windows Application

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017

I've spent hours on this `Crystal` issue but cannot get to the bottom of this.

We've recently upgraded the Windows application project from `VS2010` to `VS2017`. 
This required Visual Studio extensions - Installer projects.

Now we installed the following runtime components on the client machine:

```
CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_21.msi
CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_21.msi
```

Things did not work. I reinstalled the `CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_21.msi` version - things changed but it still did not work.

Eventually I ended up installing `CrystalReportsForVisualStudio.msi`
and everything worked.

This was not the plan though - before this change to `VS2017`, I never had to install `CrystalReportsForVisualStudio.msi`.

I extracted the files from  `CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_21.msi` vs `CrystalReportsForVisualStudio.msi.`

The latter has 13949 files vs 3476 files. All 3476 files are contained and exactly the same as their counterparts in `*CrystalReportsForVisualStudio.msi*` (but there are 10473 files not there.

How does this work - should I ever have to install `CrystalReportsForVisualStudio.msi` on a client installation (windows machine)?
Is it acceptable to do this? 
Why did it previously work on just the CRRuntime , but now it requires `CrystalReportsForVisualStudio.msi`?

There is a CRWindowsApplication.zip in `CrystalReportsForVisualStudio.msi` in  but not in  CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_21.msi. Is this perhaps required?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess:

In the references of the project try to set the CR dll's Copy local action to "Copy always" (f4 on the reference in the reference tree in solution explorer) and try to see if it works.

Comment: Hi, good point, just had a look and it is set to Copy Always - wonder if it could be the CRWindowsApplication.zip file which only exists in `CrystalReportsForVisualStudio.msi`

Comment: Ok, can you try this:

In App.Config in the startup section add: 

<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">

 leave the other properties as they are (target framework and other) if there are any and then try again

Comment: H thanks for the help so far, I can confirm that useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy was set to true. We've now run into trouble where the CrystalReportsForVisualStudio.msi we tested against was working because the specific user's machine had Visual Studio - which the clients of course does not have installed. Im now going to ask access to one of the machines that Crystal does not work on (Windows Workstation) and have a look around to see if i can find out what is missing. Thanks again for your help

Comment: we found the issue - client only had 32bit installation of runtime on his machine. installed 64 bit and all worked. Thanks for help!

Comment: nice to hear! Congrats! I didn't point out a 64bit version because I saw you had both 32/64 setup so i tought you were fine with that

Comment: Apologies, my omission, only saw it when I logged onto client machine. Many thanks again